# Run command from one server to another

Tags: mongodb

I am working with two EC2 instances. On one instance Golang code runs and on another instance Mongodb runs. Now I want to import a json file through command line for which I have written following command:

```
mongoimport --host MYIP --port 27017 --username USERNAME --password 'PASSWORD' --collection COLLECTION --db MYDB  --drop --type json --file [FILEPATH]/[FILENAME].json --jsonArray
```

when I run this command on Mongodb server then it runs there properly but when I run it on a different server (from where the connection to mongodb will be made), it gives me following error:

```
assertion: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" }
```

For username and password I logged into the database and created a user having role "readWrite".

Can anybody tell me how should I connect to it through remote server?

Thanks!

Comment: Both mongod's are at same version than your mongoimport and you are using right username/password, because mongoimport command's parameters are right.